Big query multi-statement with a declare
I'm trying to UNION ALL requests (one request by quarter).
I want to save this request as a view however I can't because the declare of date array return a first result and so I've multi-statement (I only want to have the second result).
I don't understand why.
Can you help me please ?
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE dsql STRING DEFAULT '';
DECLARE rollingdate ARRAY<DATE> DEFAULT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2024-01-07", DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 QUARTER), INTERVAL 1 QUARTER);
WHILE i <= array_length(rollingdate)
DO
  SET dsql = dsql || " SELECT *, '" || rollingdate[ORDINAL(i)] || "' AS flash_date FROM table WHERE table.date = '" || rollingdate[ORDINAL(i)] || "' union all";
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
SET dsql = SUBSTR(dsql, 1, LENGTH(dsql) - LENGTH(' union all'));
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dsql;



The first entry is from DECLARE rollingdate the 2n entry is from EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dsql;. You can shorten this to: SELECT *, date_trunc(date_column,QUARTER) as flash_date  from table where date_column > "2024-01-07" 

It doesn't work because the declare guve me severall dates and I have to do a select for each of thème ans thème, union all

I found a way to avoid some of not supported commands in standard SQL :
WITH rolling_dates AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE '2024-01-07' AS flash_date 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE '2024-01-07', INTERVAL 1 QUARTER) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE '2024-01-07', INTERVAL 2 QUARTER) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE '2024-01-07', INTERVAL 3 QUARTER) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE '2024-01-07', INTERVAL 4 QUARTER) 
)
SELECT 
  * EXCEPT(rn)
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.id, flash_date ORDER BY provided_at DESC) AS rn
  FROM table S
  CROSS JOIN rolling_dates
  WHERE deleted.at IS NULL 
    AND provided_at <= TIMESTAMP(flash_date)
) 
WHERE rn = 1

With this request, I can create my view and use it now.

Do you want to keep only the first day of the quarter?
WITH flash_date_table as (Select * from unnest(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2024-01-07", DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 QUARTER), INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)) as flash_date)

SELECT *  from 
Test.staff_time # your table with column date: cal_date
right join
flash_date_table
on cal_date=flash_date
WHERE cal_date>="2024-01-07"


I want to have the last event before thé seventh day of each quarter since january 2024
To explain, I want a "screenshot" of the status of all m'y data on the 2024-01-07, 2024-04-07, 2024-07-07, 2024-10-07 and in the future 2025-01-07 ...... And I want all these History in one view.
